# Python 2/3 Asyncio in 2019

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-asyncio

I have to keep my application compatible with Python 2 and 3 at the same time.

I have some code like the following that I want to be able to asynchronously call a function and then wait for all my futures to be resolved.

**Code:**

```python
import requests

# This would return a future
def get_xhr(url):
    return requests.get('https://www.{}.com'.format(url))

# This would return an array of futures
def get_search_engines():
    urls = ['google', 'yahoo', 'bing']
    return [get_xhr(url) for url in urls]


# Here I want to wait for all the futures to be resolved
get_search_engines()

print('All requests are done')
```

Asyncio async/await seems only compatible with Python 3.

What is the best way to be able to run functions async thats compatible for both python 2/3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Python 2 there is [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) or [Tornado](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/).

But maybe in your use case threads ([threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)) would be the easiest solution.

Also keep in mind that **Python 2 is going to be not maintained anymore at the end of 2019**.

Comment: Note that `concurrent.futures` doesn't exist on Python 2, but [a backport](https://pypi.org/project/futures/) does. With that in mind, I'd definitely recommend using `concurrent.futures` (the backport in Python 2) over raw `threading`.